# Can't find files to reference to get NUnit working on mono for F#

Tags: f#, mono, nunit

I am trying to use the nunit-console app on my mac with F# 2.0. I am using this version of mono: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.9 (tarball Mon May  7 20:25:51 EDT 2012). I cannot find the appropriate references to use when compiling my test dll.

What files do I need to reference and where can I find them?

```
fsc -r ??? module.fs tests.fs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
-r "Nunit.FrameWork.dll"
```